# NuGet dependencies - getting NU5128 warning when targetFramework is specified

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-spec

I have a project targeted to .NET Framework 4. I am using `nuget.exe` (version `5.6.0.6591`) to create the NuGet package. The project itself has no other references than `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System` assemblies (none of these have specific version set).

First, I have created a `MyProject.nuspec` file (by running `nuget spec` in the `MyProject.csproj` folder). Then I tried running `nuget pack MyProject.csproj` and got the NuGet package (the `.nupkg` archive). But I also got this warning:

```
WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:
- Add a dependency group for .NETFramework4.0 to the nuspec
```

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5128, I have modified my `.nuspec` file so that now it looks like this (note the `<dependencies>` tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>my tags here</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

However, I am still getting the warning. And when I open the `.nuspec` file within the generated `.nupkg` archive, there is only empty `<dependencies />` tag there.

One workaround I found is to substitute the variables in `.nuspec` file and call `nuget pack MyProject.nuspec` instead of `nuget pack MyProject.csproj`. Then I get this same `.nuspec` file, including the target framework dependency, within my resulting `.nupkg` archive. But this deprives me of having `nuget` automatically filling in version for me.

Either way, when I run `nuget pack` with `-Verbosity detailed`, I see the `Dependendecies` are empty:

```
Id: MyId
Version: 1.0.0
Authors: Me
Description: My description
Tags: my, tags, here
Dependencies:
```

It seems that when I call `nuget pack` on `.csproj`, it fills in the variables, but it also removes the dependencies, as it considers them empty, yet it gives me the warning afterwards. If I call `nuget pack` on `.nuspec`, it packs it as it is, including the dependencies, thus avoiding the warning.

Any ideas how could I resolve the warning while having `nuget` filling in the variables? And can the fact the target framework is not specified in my package have negative consequences for anyone using the package?

Comment: David, did you resolve your issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @DhyMik No, I haven't found the exact solution. However, I noticed there is no warning when I create the package in my TFS build plan. It uses an older version of NuGet.exe (4.1.0.2450). Dependencies are empty for the created package and everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Version 5.2.0 works as well.  I was not able to resolve the issue with versions newer than that (up to version 5.8.1).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The documentation on warning NU5128 (Scenario 1) [suggests running nuget's pack target on the project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5128) instead of calling `nuget pack`. Note that this requires your project to use `PackageReference` for its own nuget dependencies.

After installing the [NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack) package and building with `msbuild -t:pack -p:Authors=JustAGuy`, I get the nuspec dependencies automatically generated as expected.